# R default packages loaded despite using .Rprofile

Tags: r

I use R 3.5.1 in RGui/RStudio and a '.Rprofile' file in my user's home directory with a single entry to preload the package 'tidyverse': `library(tidyverse)`

When wanting to use the `filter()` function of package 'dplyr' it gets masked by the `filter()` function of package 'stats', that has been loaded as a default package AFTER sourcing '.Rprofile' in the R startup process.

This behaviour seems to be contradictory to what `?Startup` tells us: "Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced **only the base package is loaded**, so objects in other packages need to be referred to by e.g. utils::dump.frames or after explicitly loading the package concerned."

Can someone tell me please, why the default packages like 'stats' are beeing loaded despite of using a user profile file? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. When you use dplyr filter() does it work? 2. Is your .Rprofile in the same folder as the other libraries (e.g. stats)?. It's odd because I've always been able to use dplyr filter(), even when the stats package is loaded.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Ad1: {dplyr} filter() does NOT work, when {stats} is loaded AFTER loading {dplyr} via sourcing '.Rprofile' in project folder, which is odd, because due to '.Rprofile' only {base} should be loaded by R (?Startup). Ad 2: No, my '.Rprofile' is in my project folder in Windows "Documents" folder and the library {stats} is in R folder "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\library\stats". Yes, {dplyr} filter() always works when {dplyr} is loaded AFTER {stats}.

Answer (score 2):

My question has already been answered here: [R dplyr filter not masking base filter? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935095/r-dplyr-filter-not-masking-base-filter)

As outlined before, the documentation of `?Startup` says:

> Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced only the base package is loaded, so objects in other packages need to be referred to by e.g. utils::dump.frames or after explicitly loading the package concerned.

Unfortunately this can be easily misunderstood and therefore had initially led to my question. The phrase "*only the base package is loaded*" means, that only the `base` package will be loaded as the very first package in the startup process, but other default packages like `stats` will be loaded AFTER the packages sourced via an user `.Rprofile` file.

This is the reason why the `filter()` function of package `dplyr` being loaded in an user `.Rprofile` file during the startup process gets masked by the `filter()` function of the default package `stats`, being loaded AFTER the sourced user `.Rprofile` file.

Answer (score 2):

`.Rprofile` runs before R loads basic libraries
load package `stats` first

```
library('stats', warn.conflicts = TRUE, verbose = TRUE) 
library('dplyr', warn.conflicts = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```

Or alternatively, load the [conflicted package](https://conflicted.r-lib.org/) after loading your libraries. That way, the order does not matter:

```
conflicted::conflicts_prefer(dplyr::filter())
```